# How can I open the dialog from bottom but it will be show only in between half of the screen from bottom in android

Tags: android, dialog

Here is the method I tried for dialog from bottom

```
   dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.coachingtip_discover);
        ImageView imageclose = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_close1);

        TextView textsmg = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.discover_inspire_text);

        TextView textsmg2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_photo_text2);

        TextView textsmg3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_photo_text1);

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: You can Use BottomSheetDialog as like  - BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(yourView);
                dialog.show();   --prefer this link --https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295

Answer (score 1):

This is how you render the `Dialog` at the bottom :

```
dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.coachingtip_discover);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
```